# Why is Array#inject called inject?

Tags: arrays, ruby, inject

I understand the usage and purpose of `Array#inject` but why is it called `inject`? I don't understand what's being injected where.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Ruby specifically, [BTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

Comment: Trivial answer: because its main parent, Smalltalk, called it so. (actually, `inject:into:`)

Comment: @Amadan what did inject mean in smalltalk? Does it mean injecting the accumulator back into the block?

Comment: Who knows. The syntax is `ary inject: init into: block`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer to think of `inject` as "injecting" an operation among the items inside the given array and returning the final result of the calculation.

```
(1..5).inject(:+)  #=> 15
```

In my example, it takes the number 1 to 5 and "injects" a sum operation among them, resulting in `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15`.

Also, it is aliased by `reduce`, as stated with details in https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject.

Comment: What about thinking of it in terms of the accumulator? Like injecting the accumulator back into the block upon each iteration?

Comment: Yes, because it iterates over each item in the array/enumerator and applies the operation between the current item and the accumulator, "rewriting" the accumulator afterwards for the next iteration. The name `inject` is confusing, so I prefer to think of it like this.

Comment: Also one can "inject" and initial object (or value) e.g. `(1..5).inject(10,&:+) #=> 25`

Comment: I found @rodsoars approach of thinking about `inject` very interesting. I've visualized it in my [article on Ruby's inject/reduce method](https://richstone.io/ruby-inject-and-ruby-reduce-2/). I used to think of it as @engineersmnky (there's also a simple visualization for that).